# How to save data of my screen on iOS simulator to local storage (react-native)

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, local-storage, expo

I am using react-native and expo. I have some data that is displayed on the screen (this is my second screen) such as:

updated:

```
const x ="key";
const storeData = async (value) => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(movie)
    console.log(jsonValue);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(x,jsonValue)
    console.log("storing..");
  } catch (e) {
    // saving error
    console.log("error storing...");
  }
}

 const getData =  async () => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(x)
    console.log(jsonValue);
    return jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;
  } catch(e) {
    // error reading value
    console.log("error getdata");
  }
}



 let item = state.myListData.length && state.myListData[0];


let movie = (
<View>
<View
style={{
flexDirection: 'row',
backgroundColor: 'black',
alignItems: 'center',
}}>
<Text style={{ width: '50%', color: 'white' }}>{item.symbol}</Text>
<Text style={{ width: '10%', color: 'white' }} key={item.open}>
{item.open}
</Text>
<Text
style={{
width: '30%',
color: 'white',
backgroundColor: 'red',
marginVertical: 5,
paddingHorizontal: 10,
borderRadius: 10,
}}
key={item.close}>
{item.close}
</Text>
</View>

<View style={styles.bottomdata}>
<Text style={[styles.text, { alignSelf: 'center' }]} key={item.name}>
{item.name}
</Text>
<View style={styles.row}>
<View style={styles.rowItem}>
<Text style={styles.text}>OPEN</Text>
<Text style={styles.text}>{item.open} </Text>
</View>
<View style={styles.rowItem}>
<Text style={styles.text}>CLOSE</Text>
<Text style={styles.text}>{item.close}</Text>
</View>
</View>
<View style={styles.row}>
<View style={styles.rowItem}>
<Text style={styles.text}>LOW</Text>
<Text style={styles.text}>{item.low} </Text>
</View>
<View style={styles.rowItem}>
<Text style={styles.text}>HIGH</Text>
<Text style={styles.text}>{item.high}</Text>
</View>
</View>
<View style={styles.rowItem}>
<Text style={styles.text}>VOLUME</Text>
<Text style={styles.text}>{item.volumes}</Text>
</View>
</View>
</View>
);
```

How do I save this data to my screen even though if user goes back to first screen and comes back to second screen it should still be there, but it disappears at the moment since I am not sure how to store it in local storage.

I looked up online and wrote this:

```
const x = {key:"value"}
savingdata   = () => {
if (movie){
let storeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(
      'x',
      movie
    );
    console.log(storeData);
  } catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
    console.log(error);
  }
};
}
};
```

This doesn't work at all. I am new to saving data so I am not sure how to do it. If someone can please help me?

That's my whole code for second screen:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";

import {
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Keyboard,
  FlatList,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  Text,
} from "react-native";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View /* include other react-native components here as needed */,
} from "react-native";
import { useStocksContext } from "../contexts/StocksContext";
import { scaleSize } from "../constants/Layout";

// FixMe: implement other components and functions used in StocksScreen here (don't just put all the JSX in StocksScreen below)

export default function StocksScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  const { ServerURL, watchList } = useStocksContext();
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    myListData: [],
    _storeData:[]

    /* FixMe: initial state here */
  });

  const { stuff } = route.params;


  renderWithData = () => {
    return fetch(`http://131.181.190.87:3001/history?symbol=${stuff}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          myListData: json,
        });
      // console.log(state.myListData[0]);

      });
  };




  useEffect(() => {
    renderWithData();
    savingdata();
    // FixMe: fetch stock data from the server for any new symbols added to the watchlist and save in local StocksScreen state
  }, [watchList]);

  //let item = state.myListData[0];
  let item = state.myListData.length && state.myListData[0];





let movie = (
<View>
<View
style={{
flexDirection: 'row',
backgroundColor: 'black',
alignItems: 'center',
}}>
<Text style={{ width: '50%', color: 'white' }}>{item.symbol}</Text>
<Text style={{ width: '10%', color: 'white' }} key={item.open}>
{item.open}
</Text>
<Text
style={{
width: '30%',
color: 'white',
backgroundColor: 'red',
marginVertical: 5,
paddingHorizontal: 10,
borderRadius: 10,
}}
key={item.close}>
{item.close}
</Text>
</View>

<View style={styles.bottomdata}>
<Text style={[styles.text, { alignSelf: 'center' }]} key={item.name}>
{item.name}
</Text>
<View style={styles.row}>
<View style={styles.rowItem}>
<Text style={styles.text}>OPEN</Text>
<Text style={styles.text}>{item.open} </Text>
</View>
<View style={styles.rowItem}>
<Text style={styles.text}>CLOSE</Text>
<Text style={styles.text}>{item.close}</Text>
</View>
</View>
<View style={styles.row}>
<View style={styles.rowItem}>
<Text style={styles.text}>LOW</Text>
<Text style={styles.text}>{item.low} </Text>
</View>
<View style={styles.rowItem}>
<Text style={styles.text}>HIGH</Text>
<Text style={styles.text}>{item.high}</Text>
</View>
</View>
<View style={styles.rowItem}>
<Text style={styles.text}>VOLUME</Text>
<Text style={styles.text}>{item.volumes}</Text>
</View>
</View>
</View>
);


 const x = {key:"value"}
savingdata   = () => {
if (movie){
let storeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(
      'x',
      movie
    );
    console.log(storeData);
  } catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
    console.log(error);
  }
};
}
};



  return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
    <View style={styles.container}>

      {movie}

      </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

   );
}
```

I want to save data in different class, if that possible, so my code is not messy. But, saving in the same class in okay as well whatever works. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So you need to store data when user goes back to second screen but don't care if user close the app and come back? If that's the case then you can try to have both content in one screen but have second screen outside current view area and animate and show it when needed

Comment: No, it should still have the data even though user close the app and comes back.

Comment: hold on let me try with async storage

Comment: you can save it as string on asycstorage but unlike react, converting it back to component will be difficult. So I suggest you save the state of you component in different way like let currentState = {itemOneOpen: true, itemOneText: "text", other: []} then JSON.stringify(currentState) and parse it back and dynamically repopulate in terms of condition of your json object

Comment: I already saved it, but can't convert back to the component

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: Sorry for late reply. You probably have figured it out but just for other users facing the issue. Save the state of second screen on redux (optional - it is up to you to persist after app close using aync storage). Haven't used redux-persist so far but that could be solution to persist after termination. Saving components is not a solution but rather the state of the component.